# Game Engine 3D to Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine

What its the best game-engine 3D to Python 3.x and easy to install on Linux (Debian 7 "wheezy")?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the "best" - but not working on the field I am aware of few others than Blender 3D 's  game engine. Blender moved to Python 3 scripting at version 2.5, so any newer version than that will use Python 3 for BGE (Blender Game Engine) scripts.

Pygame is also available for Python 3.x, and it does feature a somewhat low-level interface to OpenGL - -sou you could do 3d with it.

Both should not have any major problems running in Debian, but maybe you will have to configure some sort of PPA to get packages being installed for Python 3.

Also, be sure that your Debian's `python3` is 3.2 - this distribution is known to have surprisingly obsolete packages even when one is running the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a game engine in python, I would recommend these:

1. Kivy (multiplatform)
2. PyGame (multiplatform)
3. Blender (graphical game engine made in python, multiplatform, also used for modeling)
4. PyOpenGL (multiplatform, 3d game engine like blender)

These are some game engines I know. You also might want to try Unity3d.

Comment: Kivy, PyGame, and Blender work on linux. Unity3d too!